# Fixed Navbar sub dropdown won't display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a custom navigation bar which i've decided to make responsive because of the mobile trend nowadays.

However when creating a sub-dropdown menu in my `fixed` nav bar, it messes up completely (wont show it correctly) and aside from that the page wont scroll down to show all the sub navigation items.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7j6ckx0g/

I've tried changing the `position` of the navbar to `static`, and that fixes the second issue but I want the navbar to be fixed.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

1st add function

```
function sybnavtop(){
    var rowheight = $('.row').outerHeight();
    $('#nav-visible').css('top',rowheight);
}
```

this function to get the height of row class div  to detrmine the top to your list and call this in window resize and call it in document load

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
        sybnavtop();
    });
```

in media screen make in #nav-visible

```
position: fixed;
overflow-y: auto !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
bottom:0;

#nav-visible {
        border-top: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 3;
        position: fixed;
        background: white;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        overflow-y: auto !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
        bottom:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7j6ckx0g/1/)

**Note :** my code to let you know how to reach your goal .. may be you will need another @media screen and (max-width : 400px) to use your list in a right way

Comment: But then it still messes up the whole look of the sub menu when clicked

Comment: @rshah read my note in answer please ..I believe you will need another media screen